# >5s Time taken for model browser control to appear on button click

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Step done to produce the bug is as written in the title.

Original file type: .nwd
Original file size: ~15.5mb
Translated file type: .svf
Translated file approx size: ~221mb
Browser: Chrome, Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Viewer version number: 5.0 & 6.0 (occurs in both)

Link to the profile.json: 
[Chrome profiling on model browser button clicked](https://drive.google.com/open?id=128P1ASpZSzk7mij1ZUuKrel9p0k7eezp)

Edit: I manage to find a pattern in reproducing this problem:

1. If no family/object is selected, model browser control load time is ~1.5 seconds (acceptable)
2. If a family/object is selected, the LOWER the location of the node in the node tree, the LONGER the time it takes for model browser control to load.  For example, selecting "BASEMENT" family and then re-open the model browser control takes only 1.5 seconds.  However, if I select "TOP ROOF" and re-open the model browser control, it takes ~6 seconds for model browser control to load (the whole page freezes during this 6 seconds)

[image: list of families]

Comment: can you confirm the Viewer version?

Comment: Happens in version 5.0 and version 6.0

Comment: I tried on `v6` and can see it takes a moment to open the model tree (maybe my model), I'm now checking with development team for details...

Comment: double checking: do you have any extensions? are you using a code similar to `Basic Application` tutorial? https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/basic-application/

Comment: Yes, I have loaded an extension that I wrote myself. Source code to the extension is here [custom extension](https://pastebin.com/Reev866v).

Comment: the extension seems related to context-menu, don't think it affects... got some improvements removing the selection features, can you try on your case? use `viewer.modelstructure.scrollToSelection = function() {}`

Comment: I will try that when I'm back to work on tuesday (thanks for actively replying)

Comment: Not including the extension doesn't affect the loading time. Disabling `scrollToSelection` feature does reduce the freeze time from 5+ seconds to ~1 seconds.

Comment: great news, submitted this as an answer, is it an acceptable workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollToSelection feature takes some time, so one workaround would be to remove it

```
viewer.modelStructure.scrollToSelection = function (){}
```

We still investigating this for further improvements

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround as the scroll to selection feature is not that important as of now until there are future changes that fixes this instead of using workaround.